# What can we say about a function whose Taylor polynomial is the same function at every point in an open interval?

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

Suppose the Taylor polynomial at $x_0$ is equal to the Taylor polynomial at $x_1$ for every $x_0, x_1$ in an open interval. Does this mean the function is constant? I am guessing it is constant since the Taylor approximations are the same for each point, hence the function is not changing. But, if true, how can I make this precise?

Comment: What does the notation $T_n(x_0, x)$ mean? In particular, are you comparing coefficients of two polynomials in $x$ or of one polynomial in $(x - x_0)$ and one in $(x - x_1)$? And does the $n$ mean that you're only comparing the $n$th derivative, or all derivatives up to $n$, or is it unnecessary complication?

Comment: Is $T_n(x_0, x) = \sum_{k=0}^{n} f^{(k)}(x_0) (x-x_0)^k / k!$?

Comment: It is the $n$-th Taylor polynomial of $f$.

Comment: In "relative" or "global" coordinates? Please give the exact definition!

Comment: I don't know what an analytic function is.

Answer (score 2):

HINT   It means that the function is a polynomial function of degree at most n

Answer (score 1):

## Hint

How does the order of the Taylor polynomial affect the result? You might want to try it for a few functions and see yourself.

## Principle

### For $T_n = f$

If a Taylor polynomial is equal to the function it approximates, it's error must be zero. The error is all the higher-order parts summed. The only way to satisfy this condition is to have all higher-order derivatives equal to zero. The only kind of functions with this property are n-th order polynomials, whose derivatives of order n+1 are definitely zero. Hence i.e. $T_5(f) = f$ holds iff $f$ is a polynomial of order $5$ or less.

### For $T_n(x_1) = T_n(x_2)$ for all $\{x_1,x_2\}$

If all the values of a polynomial are equal to each other, this indeed forces the polynomial to be a constant function. The only option of a constant polynomial is a zero-order one. What does this tell us about the original function? Either it is a constant function, or there exists a combination of different-order derivatives which cancel each other out. That would require following equality. $$a·x^n=b·x^{n+1}$$ Simple algebraic modification gives us a contradiction,$$\frac{a}{b}=\frac{x^{n+1}}{x^n}=x$$ thus the original function had to be constant.

Comment: How can I try it with a few functions? If I choose random functions, I would not get equal taylor polynomials.

Comment: Hence the idea behind the order of the polynomial. You are looking for a type of functions, whose Taylor __polynomial__ is equal to themselves, if I interpreted your question correctly. Quite specific type of functions satisfies this condition (and has already been spoiled by another answer).

Comment: Regarding your edit: The question is not asking when is a Taylor polynomial equal to the function itself. It is asking: When are the Taylor polyomials of a function at different points equal?

Comment: Alright, it seemed a bit easy that way to be honest. Following my answer, it sets a lower bound - n-th order Taylor polynomial of at-most-n-th order polynomial function is equivalent, regardless of the point of evaluation. The question which holds is whether your condition is equivalent to saying that equality $T_n=f$ is necessary.

Or I have misinterpreted the whole thing and you are talking about the __values__ of any Taylor polynomials. This would turn the question upside down, but still quite possible to answer.

Comment: I've split the answer to both ways I could imagine you intended it, hope it helps.